# Is it possible to combine the Sync Framework with the Entity Framework?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, synchronization

Before I start (re)designing my app, I would like to know beforehand: is it possible to compbine the sync framework with the Entity Framework? We are planning to use SQL Server only (for now).

Are there any known issues?

Thanks for your reply.

Bart

Answer (score 1):

Since the Sync Framework merely syncs your data to a local SQL Server instance, there should be no issue running the Entity Framework against it.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, The Sync framework moves data between databases. How you choose to access your local database is up to you. I have applications that use the Entity framework on the client side to access a sql compact 3.5 database. Theres no Stored procs allowed here so the Entity framework gives me that power. On the server side I still use more traditional datasets populated by stored procs because the SQL server is better at data manipulation.

So, yes, can mx and match.